# Typeface monospace ignored on lollipop

Tags: android, android-listview

Am trying to set `monospace` typeface to a listview in my layout but it seems lollipop ignores the set typeface. Other api versions below lollipop works just fine displaying my desired result.

**Ps**:
Am not trying to set a global font, I just want a monospace texttypeface for my listview for api >21.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

**EDIT**

```
<ListView 
android:layout_gravity="start"
 android:id="@+id/List"
 android:tag="toggle"
 android:background="#99111111"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:scrollingCache="false"
 android:typeface="monospace "
  android:dividerHeight="0.0dip" />
```

Comment: A `ListView` does not have a typeface, as a `ListView` has no text. Widgets inside of rows inside of a `ListView` might have text. Please post [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: Have edited my post adding more information.

Comment: That attribute should be ignored on all versions of Android, as [`ListView` does not support `typeface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html). You need to set the typeface on widgets in your rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Material text appearances specify the `android:fontFamily` attribute rather than `android:typeface`.

Try this for global styling,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MonospaceTextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MonospaceTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">monospace</item>
</style>
```

Now simply add the theme to your activity,

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

If your ListView is created with a custom adapter, you may also add the attribute directly inside a TextView,

```
 <TextView   
    .....     
    android:fontFamily="monospace"        
     .....
   />
```

Comment: This makes my whole app text to inherit monospace which isn't the desired result.

Comment: @CodeZero Where did you put the line?

Comment: Check the edited answer. You have two options either use a custom adapter with TextView where you can specify the font style or simply use a global styling.